# Can't mount Windows 2019 server share to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, mount, windows

I've used Ubuntu for many years, but have a problem connecting a Windows Server 2019 share to Ubuntu Server (16.04.2 LTS).

Entering

```
mount.cifs -v //192.168.xx.xx/FileServer /d2/fileserver/xxxx/ -ousername=USERNAME,domain=DOMAINNAME,sec=ntlmv2i
```

results in asking a password (ok!) and then a message arises:

```
Unable to find suitable address.
```

tried it with *sec=ntlmsspi* and *no sec parameter* without success.

Pinging the Windows server works and connecting from windows clients to the share of the windows server using the same credentials also works.

Is there anything special that's necessary to connect a Windows Server 2019 share to a 16.04 server?

Thank you for your assistance.